# small javascript problem

Tags: javascript, function

I have this little function that opens modal window type thing. The problem is that it doesnt work on IE. All other browser its fine, but on IE, nothing happends:

```
function showOverlayBox() {
if( isOpen == false ) return;
$('#full').css({
    display:'block',
    left:   ( $(window).width() - $('#full').width() )/2,
    top:    ( $(window).height() - $('#full').height() )/2,
    position:'absolute'
});
$('.BgCover').css({
    display:'block',
    width:  $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
});
}

function doOverlayOpen() {
isOpen = true;
showOverlayBox();
$('.BgCover').css({opacity:0}).animate( {opacity:0.8} );
return false;
}

function doOverlayClose() {
$('#full').css( 'display', 'none' );
$('.BgCover').animate( {opacity:0}, null, null, function() { $(this).hide(); } );
}
```

Maybe something to do with isOpen == false?

Comment: Use an alert box before the `if` condition and see what it is..

Comment: Where these elements referred by $(id) are defined. Maybe IE doesn't see them?

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted your code into this HTML snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="BgCover" style="background-color: red; display:none"></div>
<div id="full" style="display:none; background-color: yellow">Hello!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- Your code here -->

$("<span>Do it</span>").click(doOverlayOpen).insertAfter($("#full"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works as expected in Firefox *and* in IE7. So there must be something in the part you didn't show us. One idea: Are you sure `BgCover` is (and / or should be) a `class` in your HTML, and not the `id`?